# Is there a Python library for exponential spline interpolation?

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation, numerical-methods

I am working on a new model which is very sensitive to the interpolation/fit used to describe a certain dataset. I have some success with linear splines and logarithmic fits but I think there is still significant room for improvement. My supervisor suggested I take a look at exponential splines. I have found some books on the theory of exponential spines but no reference to a library or code example to follow.

Is there a library that I am unaware of that supports this feature?

Comment: [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) might have something like this in it, though I'm not sure. If you don't find anything, making a python module that does this would be an excellent open-source contribution

Comment: It appears that you've only tried linear splines, so why don't you try cubic splines (for which there are numerous implementations) before going more exotic with the exponential splines?

Comment: Why don't you show your data points ?