# Python fit data with two exponential forcing continuity

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit the following data

```
-0.63711376853067669         3.9220188494898451E-011  
-0.63559581662374798         4.0260809194317929E-011  
-0.63285142318966769         3.7912990158726701E-011  
-0.62862863903207122         3.5672466225770418E-011  
-0.61915221010943133         3.7041163107924007E-011  
-0.60375425889771406         3.7285669699125165E-011  
-0.58732715127701596         3.7394414631650330E-011  
-0.57049365955914244         3.2793779625097831E-011  
-0.55124131200928772         3.3971194033698993E-011  
-0.53006060696473212         3.2621926101891416E-011  
-0.51035174210462519         3.1395671276394652E-011  
-0.48878691498652033         3.3494235593570817E-011  
-0.46512080762899560         3.3900831760049202E-011  
-0.44144526036934528         3.0434293196110948E-011  
-0.41209308065708727         2.4384175101726714E-011  
-0.37874291229989432         2.1968353922587969E-011  
-0.34595367786265058         2.3395823530179207E-011  
-0.31308483194132991         2.2938006752405643E-011  
-0.28065779622875503         2.3677078958452214E-011  
-0.24589470583567491         2.1177013468924604E-011  
-0.20893039650026693         2.2047918048544178E-011  
-0.17289648629802296         2.2550123367583211E-011  
-0.13712730648282492         2.0960188554218161E-011  
-0.10215401377673781         2.2996586055725922E-011  
-6.7845096564425861E-002     2.0922405016890511E-011  
-3.3994983294004487E-002     2.1451489580936361E-011  
 0.0000000000000000          2.1859042406659546E-011
```

by using two exponential functions. One (blue) should fit the first half of them, and the other (red) the second half. The problem is that, since there is a gap, the continuity of the function is not granted. I would like to fit the second part by requiring that the red curve starts where the blue one ends (see figure below for better clarity). How can I impose this condition? Bounding parameters is not enough since the exponential match is achieved through an equation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def dexp(x, b, c):
    return np.exp( b*x + c )

fig1 = plt.figure( figsize=(10,10) )
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

data = np.genfromtxt('mwe.dat')
ax1.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'k+')

half = len(data)//2

popt, pcov = curve_fit( dexp, data[:half,0], data[:half,1], maxfev=100000)
x = np.linspace( np.min( data[:half,0] ), np.max( data[:half,0] ), half )
ax1.plot( x, dexp( x, *popt), 'b--', linewidth=3)


popt, pcov = curve_fit(dexp, data[half-1:,0], data[half-1:,1])
x = np.linspace( np.min( data[half-1:,0] ), np.max( data[half-1:,0] ), half )
ax1.plot( x, dexp( x, *popt), 'r--', linewidth=3)

fig1.show()
```

[Fit_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB2FJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a cubic spline interpolation.  See user14717's comment here: [Is there a Python library for exponential spline interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395825/is-there-a-python-library-for-exponential-spline-interpolation).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot interpolate. I need to put exact matching conditions over the joining point.

Comment: You want a curve between the two curves?  Am I understanding correctly?  If so, you want a piecewise fit. Splines can help you do that; they fit models through knot points but there are many other options as well.  There are more details and methods here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/reconstructing-missing-data.html.  Interesting question :)

Comment: Not really, I want the two curves to match at (roughly)  x*= -0.47. Of course, the resulting curves won't be the best fit in the two regions as the ones in the figure, but they would be a bit bent in order to match. This means that the parameters to look for are those in the space of the solution for y1 = y2, where y1 is the exponential from the right side and y2 is the polynomial from the left side